# Why are imports sorted strangely in eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse

When I organise my imports in Eclipse using Shift+Ctrl+O I get a strange order that's different to my colleagues.

For some reason, I get this order:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import start.mycompany.MyStartClass;
import com.mycompany.MyClass;
```

while my colleagues get:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import com.mycompany.MyClass;
import start.mycompany.MyStartClass;
```

All of us have the same settings in `Preferences->Java->Code Style->Organize Imports` which is java, javax, org, com.

I am on Linux and they are on Windows - we're all using Eclipse Luna at the moment.

Comment: Are you starting with things in the same order? Since you haven't told Eclipse where to put the `start` package it doesn't guarantee to put it in any particular position. The order at the start of organizing might affect what happens.

Comment: Yes, same starting position - I organise imports with no changes and the whole order changes. I think other people's imports are in alphabetical order.